# Linked servers - SQL2008 to MySql - error: 7303 - Data source

Tags: mysql, sql, datasource

**Problem:**

I use `SQL Server 2008`.

We have here a linked server, linking to a MySql Database.

But since today, when I click "test connection", it shows me this error:

( I can't post images yet):

```
The test connection to the linked server failed.


Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MANTIS".

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MANTIS" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver  
Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server,  
Error: 7303)
```

What should I do?

It was working yesterday. I thought about "data sources ( ODBC)". Yes, There is no DataSources for MySql ( it doesn't even show me the option to add a `mySql odbc` when I click `ADD`), but it was working yesterday !!

I didn't find a reasonable solution from any post.

Comment: If it is solved why did you post ??? What you want to know ???

Comment: What? it's not solved. it was working "yesterday". not today.

Comment: Ahh Ok. Let me check.

Comment: did you try all the solutions available in `Stackoverflow`. Nothing is working?

Comment: Solved!! See edit on post...

Answer (score 2):

**answer, taken from the question**
Restart server + Install MYSQL ODBC DRIVER 51 ( MySql connector )

> Start - control panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC) > System DSN > ADD
>   MySql ODBC 501 Driver